# How to get distinct rows from multiple tables in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, distinct

I have 3 tables. I want to combine these three tables and I need distinct rows only in SQL Server 2000

For example:

**Table A**

```
id
--
1  
2  
3
```

**Table B**

```
id
--
2  
3  
4
```

**Table C**

```
id
--
2  
3  
5  
6
```

The results I want is:

```
id
--
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6
```

Any suggestion would be helpful ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`UNION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) (without `ALL`), something like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT id
FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT id
FROM Table3
```